# Can't configure In-Wall AccessPoint

Tags: wireless-router, wireless-access-point, power-over-ethernet

I have bought COMFAST CF-E537AC In-wall AceessPoint on ebay, I also bought unnamed POE Injector adapter power supply with capacity of 48V 500mA.

For the life of me, I cannot access admin configuration page on the AP that should be located at ip address 192.168.10.1.
When I connect POE cable to the unit, I can see two WiFi SSIDs: COMFAST_0AC0_2G and COMFAST_0AC0_5G.

But when I try to connect to any of them it just sits there saying "getting an ip address ...".
I tried by setting static ip address, after that it says "connected", but I still cannot access a configuration IP. The same is happening if I try Wired connection.
I tried it on Win10, Linux KDE, Android 5 (802.11n), Android 9 (802.11ac), everywhere is the same. It should be working with FAT mode, but I also tried wit FIT mode with no success.

Does anybody here have some experience with how to configure in-wall AP? Did I miss something or is it possible the unit is broken?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the AP to a DHCP server you control to see whether it takes an IP ?

Comment: Yes I connected it to a router which had dhcp enabled, I could not find it or connect to it in that way either.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if your unit is capable of acting as an access point, or a router.  If this unit is typical, then when in AP mode, the two ethernet ports should be bridged.

When in router mode, the back port should be a WAN port, and the front-facing port should be LAN, which is likely the interface to which the management address is assigned, and you will need to be plugged into this port or connected to Wifi in order to obtain an IP address.

When in AP mode, you will get no IP addresses assigned to clients on the Wifi interface or the ethernet ports unless you also have a DHCP server connected to one of the ethernet ports.

I would recommend as a first test, just placing the unit into AP mode, which should be the simplest ethernet configuration with both ethernet ports bridged.  While connecting a known-good DHCP server to one of the ethernet ports, see if you can obtain an IP address with your client connected to the other ethernet port.  This will show that, at least, the configurations are working and the unit is passing data.  If that works, try connecting wirelessly, and you should still get an IP address.

If not, be aware that some improper Wifi security configurations(namely password problems) can cause a Wifi link to show connected, but never be able to obtain an IP address.

When testing a unit with a factory assigned management IP address, I usually find it simpler to test an access point when it is connected to an active DHCP server that is configured for a different subnet than the one that the AP is on, in order to eliminate the possibility of conflicts.

Whatever that case may be, or which mode you are in, the unit should respond to it's management IP address on the LAN port on the front when connected directly with a cable and a static IP address assigned to the client that is in the same subnet as the unit(but obviously not the same address).

If that doesn't work, then maybe the unit needs to be factory reset*, or the unit is defective.

*Pretty sure in your case you have tried that already...